# Auto Scroll Collelction view in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, autoscroll

I have a collection view in which each cell having images. I need to perform  an **auto scroll on the collection view** but am not getting how?

P.S. - Need to know the implementation in objective - c

Answer (score 1):

you can use scrollview method to do this

**for swift**

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath.init(item: item, section: section), at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition, animated: true)
```

**for Objective c**

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexpathofitem inSection:section] 
                    atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPosition
                            animated:YES];
```

Comment: it scrolls frequently. Is there any way to achieve a bit slower. Like scrolling with timer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] 
                        atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom
                                animated:YES];
```

//

inside a timer that  ticks say every 1 second

```
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,yValue)];
```

Comment: thanks. But it scrolls frequently. Is there any way to achieve a bit slower. Like scrolling with timer

Comment: you can set contentOffset